# How do I add an H2 tag to a page?

Tags: tags

How do I add an H2 tag to a page? The site already runs many months now. All pages are okay but some are lacking an h2 tag. Is there a simple way to add an h2 tag to these pages?

Answer (score 2):

All of the templates that generate the HTML files for the front-end of your site will live in the `templates` folder on the server Craft is installed on.

You can edit the HTML there to add `<h2>` tags anywhere you wish.

The most important thing to note about Craft CMS is it is a platform used to build bespoke solutions for clients. It is light on traditional "out-of-the-box" features and instead provides developers with a modern toolset and content teams with a great author experience. In practice, this means that every Craft site is made specifically for the client which is great and why clients and developers love us.

Here are a bunch of learning resources that should help get you up to speed quickly.

*Craft Official Docs & Support:*

- Craft CMS docs - The official [Craft CMS documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/)
- Support Services - Both free and paid first-party [support options](https://craftcms.com/support-services).
- Craft Discord group - The Craft development team is in [Discord](https://craftcms.com/discord) every day along with thousands of other Craft developers and users from all over the world.
- Craft Stack Exchange - The best place to ask "how do I" type questions. Our development team monitors [Craft Stack Exchange](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/) on a regular basis.

*Learn Craft:*

- CraftQuest - [CraftQuest](https://craftquest.io/) is our official education and training partner. They have a number of excellent free and paid resources for Craft CMS & Craft Commerce. Ryan Irelan, Mijingo's founder, also offers customized training online or on-site.
- [Tuts+ Tutorials](https://tutsplus.com/courses/search/Craft+CMS) - Not official but [very good and low cost].
- [nystudio107 Blog](https://nystudio107.com/blog) — Andrew Welch is one of the best Craft developers around and the creator of the popular [SEOmatic plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/seomatic). His regularly posts some excellent developer-oriented posts on Craft and web development.