# How to add a facebook and twitter share button on a page

Tags: plugin-social-login

I would like to add a facebook and a twitter share button to some pages of our sites. Our site already has a facebook and twitter button at some pages. Those buttons redirect to our corresponding pages.

Comment: Basically the same answer as https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/33037/57

Answer (score 3):

Facebook/Twitter look for Open Graph(OG) metadata when a page is shared. To specify what this data is, you have to include the meta tags in the head of your page.

**Step 1:**

Have meta tags for the page

e.g.

```
<head>
  <title>My Website Title</title>
  <meta property="og:url"           content="https://www.myWbsite.com/my-page.html" />
  <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
  <meta property="og:title"         content="My Website Title" />
  <meta property="og:description"   content="Page description" />
  <meta property="og:image"         content="https://www.myWebsite.com/asset/image.jpg" />
</head>
```

You can also create custom fields and call them dynamically on each page.

```
//Facebook
<meta property="og:url" content="{{ craft.app.request.absoluteUrl }}"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="{{ entry.title }}"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ entry.socialImage }}"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="{{ entry.description }}"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="{{ site.name }}"/>

//twitter
<meta name="twitter:url" content="{{ craft.app.request.absoluteUrl }}"/>
<meta name="twitter:title" content="{{ entry.title }}"/>
<meta name="twitter:description" content="{{ entry.description }}"/>
<meta name="twitter:image" content="{{ entry.socialImage }}"/>
```

I use SEOmatic plugin to make the above procedure easy. There are also other plugins available for things like this as well.

**Step 2:**

**Static URL:**

```
<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=myWebsite.com">Share on Facebook</a></li>
<li><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=myWebsite.com">Share on Twitter</a></li>
```

**or Dynamic URL:**

```
<ul>
  <li class="social facebook"><img src="facebook-icon.png" alt="Share Page on Facebook" /></li>
  <li class="social twitter"><img src="twitter-icon.png" alt="Share Page on Twitter" /></li>
</ul>
```

then add these below in JS

```
function shareWindow(url) {
    var left = (screen.width - 570) / 2;
    var top = (screen.height - 570) / 2;
    var params = "menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,width=570,height=570,top=" + top + ",left=" + left;
    window.open(url,"NewWindow",params);
}

function setShareLinks() {
    var pageUrl = encodeURIComponent(document.URL);
    var tweet = encodeURIComponent(jQuery("meta[property='og:description']").attr("content"));

    jQuery(".share.facebook").on("click", function() {
        url = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=" + pageUrl;
        shareWindow(url);
    });

    jQuery(".share.twitter").on("click", function() {
        url = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=" + pageUrl + "&text=" + tweet;
        shareWindow(url);
    })

}
```

**References:**

- https://css-tricks.com/simple-social-sharing-links/
- https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/tweet-button/overview
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this handy plugin: https://plugins.craftcms.com/simple-sharing